Why $P(y/x) = 0$?
In Stack Project Commutative Algebra 119.2, $(R,m)$ is a local Noetherian ring. In one case of the proof, $x \in m$ is a nonzerodivisor, $y \in R$ and $ym \subset xm$. Then we have a map
$$
\varphi: m \longrightarrow m, f \mapsto yf/x
$$
By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, there exists $P \in R[X]$ such that $P(\varphi) = 0$. Then the proof says "$P(y/x) = 0$" in $R_x$. Why?

I don't see the proof you're referring to in that link

@WyattKuehster, sorry. I have edited the website and it should be correct now.

This is just a direct result of $P(\varphi)(x) = 0$.
